# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.ContextImpl cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, crash

I have a fragment class which I want it to be like the Facebook feed. It gets data from a remote SQL DB and, at runtime, it creates the layout of a post and shows it in the fragment.

Is there a good & easy way to do so?

I tried to do it by using a `BackgroundTaskJobs` called from the fragment. 
This is the calling part(from inside the fragment):

```
BackgroundTaskJobs backgroundTaskJobs= new BackgroundTaskJobs(getActivity());
backgroundTaskJobs.execute();
```

And this is the init at the BackgroundTaskJobs:

```
public BackgroundTaskJobs(Context ctx){
   this.ctx = ctx;
   activity = (Activity) ctx;
}
```

At runtime this init crashes my up with the error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.admin.tabbedproject, PID: 27095
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.ContextImpl cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
```

What can i do in order to resolve this?

Comment: remove `activity = (Activity) ctx;`

Comment: But I need to use it afterwards:

`recyclerView = (RecyclerView)activity.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an easier way to do it- I passed the View variable and replaced it with the Activity initialization.

Fragment:

```
BackgroundTaskJobs backgroundTaskJobs= new BackgroundTaskJobs(getActivity());
backgroundTaskJobs.execute();
```

BackgroundTaskJobs:

```
public BackgroundTaskJobs(Context ctx, View view){
   this.ctx = ctx;
   this.view= view;
}
```

And when I needed this command:

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView)activity.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
```

I used this one instead:

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
```